# Google Fusion Intensity Map: value / coloring for Russia does not work 

Tags: dictionary, geocoding, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create an intensity map with Google Fusion Tables. Most of the country values display fine, but for some reason, the value for Russia does not appear in the 'World' view. When I switch the view to Region: 'Russian Federation' , it works fine (although the color is not correct).

I tried changing from Russia to Russian Federation, RU etc. but I keep having the same problem.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: What kind of data are you using? Can you provide a link to your table? Otherwise it's quite difficult to tell what's wrong...

Comment: Hi Odi, here's the link to the data set: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1OB-lilel2ZMNyU73V4MveYkjBdpN8QJZrO1OJNg

Comment: It's arms exports by country for 2011

Comment: (and here's the link to the map: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=MAP&gco_region=world&gco_dataMode=regions&containerId=gviz_canvas&q=select+gvizcountry(col0)%2C+col1%2C+col0+from+1OB-lilel2ZMNyU73V4MveYkjBdpN8QJZrO1OJNg&qrs=+where+gvizcountry(col0)+%3E%3D+&qre=+and+gvizcountry(col0)+%3C%3D+&qe=+limit+43&width=500&height=300)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173438), you must use the [two-digit country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) for the intensity map to work.

I copied your table and replaced "Russia" with "RU" and then it works:

- [Map](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=MAP&gco_region=world&gco_dataMode=regions&containerId=gviz_canvas&q=select%20gvizcountry%28col0%29,%20col1,%20col0%20from%201yroo2IdDs41DlsgLHKCAVGXfaIpstXWXMiNKcvk&qrs=%20where%20gvizcountry%28col0%29%20%3E=%20&qre=%20and%20gvizcountry%28col0%29%20%3C=%20&qe=%20limit%2043&width=500&height=300)
- [Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1yroo2IdDs41DlsgLHKCAVGXfaIpstXWXMiNKcvk)